# Jquery-Steps : jquery key events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on [Jquery-Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/),

i need to check password strength on key up as

```
$("#checkpass").keyup(function(){ $('#checkpass').pstrength();});
```

Which is working fine other than jquery-steps pages.

how can we add click and keyup events here ?

Comment: Do you want to add .click event for $("#checkpass") ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this 
<script>
            $(function ()
            {
                $("#wizard").steps({
                    headerTag: "h2",
                    bodyTag: "section",
                    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                    stepsOrientation: "vertical"
                });
    //add the keyup functions within the jquery ready functions

    $("#checkpass").keyup(function(){ alert($('#checkpass').val().length);})
    $("#checkpass").click(function(){ alert("you are here");})

     // code added within ready functions
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: The key, as @Silz said, is attach the listeners after jquery.step initialization code

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkpass").on('keyup click',function(){ $('#checkpass').pstrength();});
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed jquery-steps Event "onStepChanging"

so I used it like

```
onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
{
  $("#checkpass").keyup(function(){ $('#checkpass').pstrength();});
}
```

It's working :)